# Gradle -- Eclipse classpath still include the jar files that are excluded in the build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, gradle-eclipse

I'm trying to exclude few jars from the .classpath file which is generated by the gradle eclipse plugin. Though i do the following stuff in my build.gradle to exclude these jars, the classpath still contains these jar files.

```
configurations {
    eclipseExcludedDeps
}

dependencies {
    eclipseExcludedDeps group: "javax", name:"javaee-api", version: "${versions.javaee_api}"
    eclipseExcludedDeps group: "javax.xml.parsers", name:"jaxp-api", version: "${versions.jaxp_api}"
    eclipseExcludedDeps group: "xerces", name:"xmlParserAPIs", version: "${versions.xmlParserAPIs}"
}

eclipse {
    wtp {
        component {
            minusConfigurations << configurations.eclipseExcludedDeps
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried all the approaches mentioned in the gradle docs but none of the them works for me. 
I'm using gradle version 2.7. To create the classpath i run 'gradle eclipse' command.
Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a WTP user myself but I think you'll need to configure `eclipse.classpath`

```
eclipse {
   classpath {
       minusConfigurations += [ configurations.eclipseExcludedDeps ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this approach earlier but the classpath still includes those jars. I doubt if it has to do with the gradle version (2.7) im using.